# PrimeNG Datatable cell editor fill the cell

Tags: css, primeng, primeng-datatable

I use the following code to customize editor in my primeng datatable:

```js
<p-column field="vin" header="Vin" [editable]="true">
  <ng-template let-col let-car="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="car[col.field]" appendTo="body"></textarea>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

But I can't find out how do I make the editor fit the size of the cell.
I only managed to fit width with this css code applied to the `<textarea>`:

```css
.cell-editor {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would fix N rows for the textarea (3 for example) :

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="car[col.field]" appendTo="body" class="datatableTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
```

and apply the 100% width to the textarea tag :

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vxamj7Yu4dF1AnkbrFf6?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if we have a second column with less text and we click to edit "Audi Audi Audi ..." the row will vertically shrink and I would like to avoid this. [Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PC44OOq6aaTo47YwKLvf?p=preview)